# Pseudocode for a program that will display EE bonus amount based on Dept number he works

Tags: function, pseudocode

I am doing homework for my class. I am struggling to find what is likely a simple answer. I should mention the chapter is Input Validation Loop.

I am supposed to write pseudocode for a program that will display an employee's bonus amt based on the department where he works.  The program should begin by prompting the user for the EE's worker identification number (WIN) that has exactly 5 characters (which may include letters and/or digits. Then I need to use an error trap to prevent the program from continuing until the user enters a valid WIN.

The program should then prompt the user for the employee's department number. There are 15 dept numbers in this company, numbered 101 to 115. Use another error chart to prevent the program from continuing until the user enters a valid department number.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Declare a variable to hold the WIN

Declare String employeeIdNo

//Prompt the user to enter WIN

Display “Please enter employee’s worker’s identification number”

Input employeeIdNo

//If necessary, adjust the number you entered

While length (employeeIdNo) = 5 Then 

    Display “Error!  The WIN must be exactly 5 letters or digits”

    Display “Please try again:”

    Input employeeIdNo

End While


//Return type is a Boolean

Function Boolean _____________( )

    Declare Real bonusAmt

    //Get the department number

    Display “Please enter the employee’s department number”

    Input __________ 


    //If necessary, adjust the number you entered

    Display “Error! Please enter a valid department number “

    Display “Please try again:”

    Employee will earn a bonus of $____

    Return bonusAmt

End Function
```

What I am trying to figure out is do I need to call the function in the top loop? Also, am I on the right track for displaying the dept and bonus amount in the function? 
Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you step through your code imagining that you are in the actual application. Try to come up with edge cases and make sure it handles everything. This is not specific to this question, but seeing as your question might be indicative of broader approach, I figured I'd bring it up anyways.

And make sure your class' academic honesty policy allows you to post this kind of questions online. Mine certainly have not

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I am not sure I understand exactly what you are saying to do. Programming is new to me, and this class is a basic programming and logic course, so I am very slowly understanding it. For this assignment, because it is a homework assignment in a specific chapter, I have to answer it based on what we have already learned. This is only Ch 7, so functions, modules, booleans, do while, do until, while and for loops have only been introduced.

Comment: Basically I meant, just walking through each step as if you were the computer, and making sure what you are doing makes sense. Then trying to find situations that might break that (i.e. edge cases), which you then use to adapt your approach until you think you have the right solution.

Comment: That is what I thought I was doing above. Thank you for your comments.